# SQL Order Table and put a value instead of Date

Tags: sql, date, window-functions

I have a table and I am sorting by date. What I want to do is add a new column or convert this column with the date in a ordered value. For example:

Imagine this query:

```
Select Name, Info, Creation_Date
From Table_1
order by Creation_Date
```

If I get the next values, what I want is put a new column order by Creation_Date and in that column the value representing the order by date should appear.

```
B info1 2020-05-19 07:50:11.231 -> 1
J info2 2020-02-19 08:12:14.150 -> 2 
C info3 2020-02-19 10:11:51.332 -> 3
U info8 2020-02-19 11:53:12.253 -> 4
I info5 2020-02-19 12:43:21.510 -> 5
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports window functions, just use `row_number()`:

```
select Name, Info, Creation_Date, row_number() over(order by Creation_Date) rn
From Table_1
order by Creation_Date
```